# Why my confusion matrix report valued zero

Tags: python, speech-to-text, speech, confusion-matrix

So i tried to do some speech to text recognition and the code was successfuly predicted the  speech data into text output. Then, i want to use confusion matrix to evaluate to evaluate the accuracy of classification. but the matrix was valued 0 and the precision , re-call, f1 score was valued 0 too.

this is the code:

```
if types == 1: 
        start_index = test_file.find('\')+1
        end_index = test_file.rfind('\')+1
        print('Predictions: ')
        print()
        print('Audio file:',test_file, start_index, end_index)
        original_label = test_file[end_index:]
        print('Original: {}'.format(original_label.split('/')[1]))
        print('Predicted: {}'.format(predicted_label))
        print()
        y_test.append(original_label.split('/')[1])
        predicted_labels.append(predicted_label)
    else:
        start_index = test_file.find('\') + 1
        end_index = test_file.rfind('\')+1
        original_label = test_file[end_index:]
        y_test.append(original_label.split('/')[1])
        predicted_labels.append(predicted_label)


cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predicted_labels)
print(cm)
print(classification_report(y_test, predicted_labels))
```

and this is the result of confusion matrix report:

[The Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjA4c.jpg)

I just want to know why, almost of all the value is 0.
thanks!

Comment: Don't post code as an image! Post it as text.

Comment: @trincot okay done, because i was new. Sorry :D